# find control inside asp:panel in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have ASP:Panel which is visible false initially  , and have another radio button list  having value yes or no 
on click of yes my panel gets visible true ,
now my problem is  when i click yes my panel is visible  ,but in jquery i am not able to find conrol which is placed inside panel

Jquery

```
    jQuery("[id$='p_lt_ctl01_ContentPageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl13_editabletext1_ucEditableText_widget1_ctl00_chkVndr']").change(function () {
        debugger;
        var chkval = jQuery('input[id*=chkVndr]:checked').val();
        if (chkval == "Yes") {
            alert(12346);


            document.getElementById('<%= txtDtOfServ.ClientID %>').keypress(function (event) {
  // jQuery("#p_lt_ctl01_ContentPageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl13_editabletext1_ucEditableText_widget1_ctl00_txtDtOfServ_dtPicker_txtDateTime").keypress(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

            });

        }
        else {
            jQuery("#p_lt_ctl01_ContentPageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl13_editabletext1_ucEditableText_widget1_ctl00_txtDtOfServ_dtPicker_txtDateTime").keypress(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

            });

        }

     });
```

Control structure

```
       <asp:Panel ID="Vendordtl" runat="server" Visible="false">

    <my:myDateTimeControl ID="txtDtOfServ" runat="server" IsRequired="true" NeedsValidation="true" EditTime="false" DisplayNow="false" />
<asp:Pane/>
```

Comment: Use ClientID to get the control e.g. $('#' +' <%= txtDtOfServ.ClientID) %>')

Comment: this not works  , i have tried this

Comment: Check the source what id you have to element you are looking for? just alert this id on checkbox change

Answer (score 0):

Because the `DateTimeControl` is a child of the panel you have to go through the panel first.

Try something like:

```
 document.getElementById('<%= Vendordtl.FindControl("txtDtOfServ").ClientID %>')
```

Comment: Check the console from your browser and see if it shows any error

Comment: no nothing showing if i alert the id above specified then it will just show object object